# Git, how to "force" a squash rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I need to "squash" some commits together. Normally I am used to do something like this:

`git rebase -i HEAD~10`

However, now I am getting the error below:

> error: could not apply 2009972... fixes
>
> When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue". If
>   you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead. To
>   check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase
>   --abort".

As you can see `git` pretends that I resolve all the conflicts. Now, I **do not want** and cannot resolve any conflicts.

What I need is a way to tell `git` something like: "Hey, I do not want to merge anything: just take all the tracked files in this branch - as they appear in the last commit/HEAD, discard/remove the previous 10 commits before the latest one, and finally "apply" these files as a new commit":

For example, suppose this is a list of all commits hashes:

`1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12`, where HEAD points to 12.

I want to squash/remove/whatever this operation is called all the commits from 2-11 included, so that the final result after a `git log` gives:

`1-12`

where **the files before and after the operation must be the same**.

What are the commands to obtain what I need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution (after aborting the current rebase) is:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~10
```

Now, your HEAD has moved ten commits back, but none of your files changed: they'll all show up as new changes to be committed.

Then, just commit them as normal.

---

The downside to this approach is that you lose access to the intermediate commit messages when you're writing your new commit message.

The alternative is to make the original `rebase -i` command work for you by by specifying conflict resolution strategy *theirs*:

```
$ git rebase -i -s theirs HEAD~10
```

It would be interesting to know how you've managed to get conflicts in the first place though, `rebase -i` should usually apply cleanly. Unless some of those ten commits are themselves merges?

Comment: thanks, I forgot about the --soft, however I am interested in the second solution can you explain me what theirs does exactly and what you mean "work for you"?

Comment: See the merge & rebase documentation for an discussion of the strategies: rebase -i replays your patches one-by-one in order, and `-s theirs` means _if there is a conflict, take the new state_ (ie, from the commit rebase is currently replaying).

Comment: I got git: 'merge-theirs' is not a git command. Do I have an old version?

Comment: `git help merge` and read the section on merge strategies, or read [the book](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies). Just bear in mind while rebase is running, "our" tree means the original one at HEAD~10 plus local changes from patches already replayed, and "their" tree is the one in the patch currently being replayed.

Comment: Is this preferable over cherry picking?

Comment: I'm not sure how cherry-picking merge commits works out in practice, and the cherry-pick behaviour for ranges is non-trivial, so I usually avoid it. Also, of course, cherry-pick won't update the picked-from branch, which is what OP seemed to want.